# Can I use python "re.sub" instead of "sed"?

Tags: python

I would like to convert a command from one line to multiple:

Example Input:

```
myprog  -library lib -topcell top -view layout
```

Output:

```
myprog \
          -library  lib\
          -topCell  top\
          -view  layout\
```

I can do that using "sed" as following:

```
echo $cmd | sed 's/\s-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s/\\\n\t & /g'
```

But I can't replicate that by python using re.sub.
What I noticed is that re.sub doesn't accept a regular expression as a second argument as following:

```
>>> re.sub(r'-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s',r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s',cmd)

‘myprog [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\slib [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\stop [a-zA-Z0-9]*\\slayout'
```

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python it would be like,

```
>>> s = "myprog  -library lib -topcell top -view layout"
>>> print re.sub(r'(-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s)',r'\\\n\t\1', s)
myprog  \
    -library lib \
    -topcell top \
    -view layout
>>> print re.sub(r'(-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s)',r'\\\n\t \1 ', s)
myprog  \
     -library  lib \
     -topcell  top \
     -view  layout
```

In sed `&` in the replacement part prints the matched characters. In python, i just used capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about \1 and print functionality!

Answer (score 1):

```
x="myprog  -library lib -topcell top -view layout"
print re.sub(r"(?=-)",r"\\\n\t",x)
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks. That will also work, but using (?=-) will create a problem if my program value include - for example -library lib-1

Comment: @Monster the answer you accepted will validate `- ` see https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/3 also see the lasst line.You shouls use `(?=-\w+(?:\s|$))` in case you want to be fail proof